# why do I get "info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1305'" when compiling a program with eigen in msvc

Tags: visual-c++, eigen, simd, auto-vectorization

I wrote some code to do eigen calculation, and I add /Qvec-report:2 to see whether avx is activated in eigen. But I get so many "info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1305'". It seems that the eigen struct is too complex for msvc...Or did I miss something?

The code is:

```
vector<double> ptsDataVec(12000);
int ptsNum = ptsDataVec.size() / 4;
Eigen::Matrix4Xd pts = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix4Xd>(ptsDataVec.data(), 4, ptsNum);
Eigen::Matrix4d myE = Eigen::Matrix4d::Identity();
Eigen::Matrix4Xd abc = myE * pts;
```

The info I got:

> c:\visionlibs\eigen3\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\util\memory.h(288) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1305'
>
> c:\visionlibs\eigen3\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\assignevaluator.h(484) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1305'

many info like this. So what's wrong?

Comment: Where does Microsoft document reason 1305?  Hard to guess what it doesn't like from an opaque reason code.  Also, is the generated assembly code using AVX at all?  Look at a [mcve] of your code on https://godbolt.org/ and look for use of YMM registers, and `vmulpd` (packed double) and other math instructions, not just `...sd` (scalar double).  If those loops in inline helper functions weren't the critical parts of the algorithm, but some other loop was vectorized, then it could still be fine.

Comment: Eigen already "manually" vectorizes expressions like the one you are computing: https://godbolt.org/z/seozE3fYj (the main loop essentially does only broadcast-loads and `vmulpd` and `vfmaddpd`). I don't know about the MSVC warning, but maybe it tries to vectorize the already vectorized loop again.